# Pokemon GO Login

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I have a question about signing in to Pokemon GO. My phone is signed in with another email that I use. But when I first opened the app (after I clicked the sign in with gmail button) , it signed in with the email that was on my phone.I wanted to use another email on the game because originally I started the game on another phone with that other email. How do I make it that I use the other email that I wanted to use because by default the game is using the email on my phone!( I am using a galaxy phone with google play if this information helps ) Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Log out of your google play and log out of your Pokémon Go then it will let you log in with the email you want to use. After log in back into your Google play